# Does "要超高15天" mean "15 days at most" or "more than 15 days"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I asked my supplier how long to produce something in green color.

> 做绿色的要多长时间？

They replied

> 要超高15天

Does "要超高15天" mean "15 days at most" or "more than 15 days"?

Comment: I reckon there's a typo in your supplier's response; in all possibility he meant "要超**过**十五天", which would be "more than 15 days".

Comment: @magni It is the answer I would write

Comment: Why don't you ask for a clarification? To me, 超高 is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "高" is a typo, "要超过十五天" wouldn't make sense either. If the intention is "15 days or more," people typically say "at least 15 days," which is "至少十五天" in Chinese. However, "要超过十五天" would make sense if you had explicitly asked, "Can you do this within 15 days?"

If "高" is not a typo, then "要超高15天" seems to imply that it will be an additional 15 days beyond some contextually referenced period (XXX). This is just my interpretation. Even if someone truly meant an additional 15 days beyond XXX, saying "要超高15天" would still not make sense.

Answer (score -2):

the supplier's answer is saying "exceed beyond 15 days." The key word here for clarification is 超: exceed, surpass, etc. 高 also helps show it being "above" 15.

If they were saying "at most 15 days" you would instead see a phrase like 至多15天 or maybe 最多15天 etc.

I don't know the context, but at face value I would interpret it as taking around 15 days, but easily having something else to make it a bit longer so they don't say 15 exactly (such as shipping or gathering the materials at the start etc.)

Comment: The question is, is 超高 a typo? I feel that it need not be so. 超高 could readily be understood as "more than" because the following words 15天 provide a necessary semantic context. Perhaps it is a regional thing?

Comment: @WayneCheah Personally I don't see it as a typo, since I think it's intentional and has everything there that's needed.  I agree fully that adding more characters to clarify would be more proper grammatically. I just think its a casual/spoken type answer rather than error.  Could definitely be area differences or even anecdotal/personal preferences varying too.

Comment: I say the supplier somehow mistyped 過(guò) into 高(gāo)  instead